# print values in custom format in AWK

Tags: bash, shell, awk, text-processing, gawk

How do I align min and max values shown below

## Program

```
{
    for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
    {
    a[i] = $i;
    if (min[i]==""){  min[i]=$i;} #line1
    if (max[i]==""){  max[i]=$i;} #line2
    if ($i<min[i]) {  min[i]=$i;}     #line3
    if ($i>max[i]) {  max[i]=$i;}     #line4
    }
print $0;

}
END {
OFS="\n";
for(j = 1; j <= NF; j++)
        {   
        print min[j],max[j];        
        }
}
```

## Dataset

```
4 14 24 34
3 13 23 33 
1 11 21 31
2 12 22 32
5 15 25 35
```

## Current Output

```
4 14 24 34
3 13 23 33 
1 11 21 31
2 12 22 32
5 15 25 35
1
5
11
15
21
25
31
35
```

## Output I need

```
4 14 24 34
3 13 23 33 
1 11 21 31
2 12 22 32
5 15 25 35
1 11 21 31  ->   Min Values(for that field)
5 15 25 35  ->   Max Values(for that field)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop twice, once for the min, once for the max:

```
END {
    for(j = 1; j <= NF; j++) printf "%d ", min[j]
    print ""
    for(j = 1; j <= NF; j++) printf "%d ", max[j]
    print ""
}
```